# echoing summation result

Tags: php

please i am trying to echo the sumation of a column in the next row
, but it is displaying with the prev row.

this is the code

```
 $body = "<html><body><table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Shop Name</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Size</th>
<th>Color Name</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Cost</th>
</tr>";
$totalPrice = 0;
$pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");   
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)){ 
    $body .= "<tr>
        <td>" . $row['Sname'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Pname'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Psize'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Pcolour'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Pquantity'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Price'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Tprice'] ."</td>
        </tr>";
         $totalPrice += $row['Tprice'];
}
$body .= "<tr>

            <td>" . $totalprice ."</td>
        </tr>";

$body .="</table></body></html>";
```

Comment: Why are you making the same SQL query twice? Either store the result of the first query or let the DB do the summation. Also, it does not seem you have initialized `$totalprice` anywhere.

Comment: so what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to display the total under the last column right?

for that you will need to add some td' s in the later tr i.e.,

```
$body .="<tr>
        <td colspan=6></td>
        <td>" . $totalprice ."</td>
    </tr>";
```

Even your code is not appropriate. Why would you iterate through that while loop twice for the same mysql query result set,

```
$pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");   
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)){ 
    $body .= "<tr>
        <td>" . $row['Sname'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Pname'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Psize'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Pcolour'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Pquantity'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Price'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Tprice'] ."</td>
    </tr>";
    $totalprice += $row['TPrice'];
}

$body .="<tr>
            <td colspan=6>Total :</td>
            <td>" . $totalprice ."</td>
        </tr>";


$body .="</table></body></html>";
```

Comment: i want to display the total, on a new row, after the while as been executed

Comment: The above block of code will print the total price in a new row as you need it to print

Comment: i have updated the code with the one i have, please help have a look, as i a think, it might be the table header causing the problem

Comment: Pls add <td colspan=6></td> to the last tr

Answer (score 1):

Give the `td` a colspan of 7, so it's 100% wide:

```
$body .="<tr>
    <td colspan="7">" . $totalprice ."</td>
    </tr>";
```

Also you can improve efficiency by summing the prices in your query:

```
SELECT *, SUM(Tprice) AS total_price FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'
```

or

```
SELECT Sname, Pname, Psize, Pcolour, Pquantity, Price, Tprice, SUM(Tprice) AS total_price FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'
```

then in your PHP

```
$body .= ... $row['total_price'] ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, why are you running the same query twice? You can do the summation in the same iteration as when you're writing out the rows:

```
$body = "<html><head><title></title></head><body><table>";
$totalPrice = 0;
$pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");   
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)){ 
    $body .= "<tr>
        <td>" . $row['Sname'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Pname'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Psize'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Pcolour'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Pquantity'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Price'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Tprice'] ."</td>
        </tr>";
    $totalPrice += $row['Tprice'];
}
// echo "$totalprice";
// Add a column with colspan 6 to push the totalprice column under the Tprice column.
$body .= '<tr>
            <td colspan="6">
            <td>' . $totalprice ."</td>
        </tr>";


$body .="</table></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `colspan` like `<td colspan=7>" . $totalprice ."</td>`